# SharePoint Online filtering a person/group field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to be able to limit the users available in a user/group field, depending on what the user has chosen from a dropdown.

The main concern is if it's even possible to limit the user-field dynamically (maybe by group etc).
Does anyone know any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in client people picker.

Refer [here](https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/sharepoint-2013-restrict-client-people-picker-users-to-particular-sharepoint-group/)

This is done with SPHosted app. You can create a client people picker in you default sharepoint form by using content editor webpart.